Lua table.insert refuses to work unless the expression given as second arg is saved to a var first
Observe the behavior from the repl:
❯ lua
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> tab={}; str='a'; z=str:gsub('a', 'b'); table.insert(tab, z); print(tab[1])
b
> tab={}; str='a'; table.insert(tab, str:gsub('a', 'b')); print(tab[1])
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'insert' (number expected, got string)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'table.insert'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
>


This question is similar to: expected table, got number when replacing strings with gsub. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

string.gsub() returns two values. Therefore, table.insert() sees three arguments: table.insert(tab, 'b', 1). Three-argument call is supposed to be table.insert(t, pos, value) but pos here is a string, so it fails.
You have to embrace gsub in order to get rid of that extra value:
table.insert(tab, (str:gsub('a', 'b')))


I figured it out while I was preparing for bed. Yeah, it's two return values. Damn Lua, this feature is kinda naughty.
